# iphone os 4.0 adding images to simulator 4.0 folder

Tags: iphone

i have two iphone SDK 3.0 and 4.0 on two different folders i want to add images to my iphone simulator 4.0 how could i do that the directory such as application support/media/ does not shows when selecting iphone simulator 4.0 please guide me how i could do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag and save technique doesn't seem to work for 4.0 simulator.  It works fine for 3.1.2, but not 4.0.  Any ideas why?  I've also added the .MISC directory with .THM files.

Answer (score 5):

Simply drag the picture you want to save on your iPhone Simulator. It will open in Safari. After that it is like on the original iPhone: Click and hold, press "Save image".